# I need help changing integers to words in Python 3.4.3

Tags: python

Example: 1 = one.

All I need to do is make a count go up to 5, but I am terrible at coding and am struggling. The code requirement is to count from the number input between 2-5 and count UP to five, but the last requirement is that the output must be WORDED numbers.

```
num = int(input('Enter a number (2-5): '))
count = 2
while count <= num:
    if num > 5:
        print('invalid.')
        num = int(input('Enter a number (2-5): '))
    print(count)
    count = count + 1
```

My desired print would be:

```
Enter a number (2-5): 
INPUT '5'
Two
Three
Four
Five
```

or

```
Enter a number (2-5):
INPUT '3'
Two
Three
```

CURRENTLY I am getting:

```
Enter a number (2-5): 
INPUT '5'
2
3
4
5
```

Comment: You'll need a list of the words for the numbers.

Comment: Or use https://pypi.python.org/pypi/inflect if you have a lot where using a list wouldn't be the best option

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python doesn't really recognize 'words' as they relate to numbers. Words representing numbers is a very human thing.

What you need is a dictionary where the string version of the number is the key and the value is the corresponding word.

For example:

```
words_num_dict = {1: 'one', 2: 'two', 3: 'three', 4: 'four', 5: 'five'}
num = int(input('Enter a number (2-5): '))
count = 2
while count <= num:
    if num > 5:
        print('invalid.')
        num = int(input('Enter a number (2-5): '))
    print(words_num_dict[count])
    count = count + 1
```

More info on using dictionaries [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_dictionary.htm).

Comment: and how would I do that?

Comment: @Hugo0206 haha that was fast! I just wanted to give you something to chew on while I update my answer. Don't worry i am adding code :D

Comment: @Hugo0206 try the code I added. I don't have access to a python interpreter right now, so let me know if anything goes wrong. This all kind of based in my head :P

Comment: Thank you very much for the update! Upon inputting that code I get an error print(words_num_dict(str(count)))
TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable

Comment: @Hugo0206 fixed it. i used parentheses instead of brackets. sorry about that! XD

Comment: @Hugo0206 if this is a solution to your question, please mark it as correct for future programmers. Thanks!

Comment: I will do! I have three minutes until I can! Thank you so much!!!!!! You have helped me through a two hour rage session!

Comment: @Hugo0206 no worries haha, thats what we are here for!

Answer (score 0):

This is a modified version of your code. Try it and let me know if this is what your program is supposed to do.

```
num = int(input('Enter a number (2-5): '))
#list of numbers that are to be printed out
list = ['two', 'three', 'four', 'five']
#checks if number is less than 5. if not, enters a while loop
if num > 5:
    while num > 5:
        print('invalid.')
        num = int(input('Enter a number (2-5): '))
#checks if number is less than or equal to five. if so, prints all numbers from "two" to selection
if num <= 5:
    print (list[0:num-1])
```